# Is possible to remove "on fly" the full path using tar?

Tags: tar, pax

I have some mp3 on various dir.
I did

```
find $HOME -name *.mp3|pax -wf arch.tar
```

The command works fine,but when extract, it recreate the full dirs
for example

```
tar -tvf arch.tar
```

Return

```
dir1/dir2/sound.mp3
dir3/music.mp3
dir4/dir5/anotherdir/anothermusic.mp3
```

When extract of course will create a lot of dirs.
My desire is a thing like this

```
find $HOME -name *.mp3|pax -w"possibleoption" -f arch.tar
```

To obtain an archive like this

```
/sound.mp3
/music.mp3
/anothermusic.mp3
```

I know is not safe,but is possible to strip dir path on fly?

p.s= I used pax command for example, but the classical tar is also good

Comment: Please look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295771/how-do-i-extract-files-without-folder-structure-using-tar

Comment: Add as answer,if none put a better answer I can vote as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These variations all assume that you've created an archive with the original path stored in the archive itself.  They transform the path when listing/extracting the archive.

Using `pax` with its `-s` flag:

```
pax -f archive.tar -s '@.*/@/@' '*.mp3'
```

Add `-r` at the start to actually extract the files.

With BSD `tar`:

```
tar -tf archive.tar -s '@.*/@/@' '*.mp3'
```

Change `-t` to `-x` to actually extract the files.

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar -tPf archive.tar --transform 's@.*/@/@' --show-transformed-names --wildcards '*.mp3'
```

Change `-t` to `-x` to actually extract the files.

The string replacement will remove the path stored in the archive and replace it with a single `/`.

---

The equivalent operation for creating an archive with files whose pathnames are read from standard input (transforming the names by replacing the path with `/`):

`pax`:

```
pax -w -f archive.tar -s '@.*/@/@'
```

BSD `tar`:

```
tar -c -f archive.tar -s '@.*/@/@'
```

GNU `tar`:

```
tar -c -f archive.tar --transform='s@.*/@/@' --files-from=-
```

Comment: pax works fine with find,tar give error if read from stdin with those options

Comment: @elbarna See updated answer.

Comment: Ok,perfect,voted as solution

Comment: @Kusalananda is there a reason for not mentioning the oldest free `tar` implementation (`star`)?  `star` started in 1982 and is faster and more powerful.. (e.g. built in `find`), `star` is also able to emulate the CLI from `cpio`, `pax`, ... BTW: there are many `pax` implementations and many of them are bad or implement too few of the official features.

Comment: @schily Yes, there is a reason. None of the systems I work with has it installed and I have no experience with it.

Comment: @Kusalananda you sould fetch a recent `schilytools` and give it a try. None of the other tar implementations implements the features, I need for my every day work and GNU tar in addition is not mature enough to be in a list of useful software I like to use.